# MSAL + Azure App Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-msal

I've posted this before, but the thread became pretty extensive and confusing and a resolution was never met. I'm reposting with a clear and concise block of code and my desired outcome.

I'm looking to use client-flow authentication for an Azure App Services backend.
I'd like to use MSAL, to support both Microsoft Accounts (MSA) and AAD accounts. Been stuck on this for weeks with no resolution in sight.

```
PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication("registered-app-id-in-apps.dev-portal");                            
string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await myApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
JObject payload = new JObject();                            
payload["access_token"] = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
payload["id_token"] = authenticationResult.IdToken;                            
user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

Why doesn't this work?
What do I have to do to get it to work?

Getting a 401 exception, tried with MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory as well as MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Microsoftaccount

--App Service Auth Config for Microsoft Account:

ClientID and ClientSecret as it appears in apps.dev.microsoft.com

--App Service Auth Config for AAD:

ClientID as it appears in apps.dev.microsoft.com

Issuer URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Client Secret: (Blank)

Comment: I have created a test demo  in my computer, I have reproduced your issue.I found the azure app’s Azure Active Directory using express settings doesn’t support azure ad v2.0.But the MSAL needs azure AD v 2.0.  I suggest you could try to server flow to enable both AD and MSFT account login.You just need to add two button in the login page to enable different account. More details, you could refer to this url:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow

Comment: Part of my requirement is I need to be able to access the MS Graph from my backend. Using server flow allows me to access the graph when logging in with AAD but does not work for Microsoft accounts. Also I used advanced settings, not express, and the client id is the registered app in apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same issue, having set up Azure Active Directory authentication on the App Service & attempting to authenticate from a WinForms client using MSAL. Turns out that, as of the time of this writing, Azure App Service does not support AAD V2 (including MSAL). Found the below note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad):

*At this time, AAD V2 (including MSAL) is not supported for Azure App Services and Azure Functions. Please check back for updates.*

So ADAL seems to be the only viable option at the moment, unless you handle the authentication inside your backend code yourself.